# What is the difference between the parameter containing the database column and a direct string containing parameter?

Tags: sql

Need the solution to solve taking string from the database and replacing the parameter.

Here are the sample queries I used to understand more:

```
--Create Table Table1
--(
--Id int primary key identity(1,1),
--Data varchar(max)
--)

--Create Table Table2
--(
--Id int primary key identity(1,1),
--SampleData varchar(max)
--)

Delete From Table1
GO

Delete From Table2
Go

insert into Table2 (SampleData) values ('How r u ''+@i+''. ')

Declare @i int = 100
Declare @TempSampleData varchar(max) = NULL

While(@i > 0)
begin
    Set @TempSampleData = (select SampleData from Table2)
    insert into Table1 (Data ) values (@TempSampleData)
    insert into Table1 (Data) values ('How r u '+Cast(@i as varchar(500))+'.')
    set @i = @i - 1
End
```

--Output

```
Id  Data
103 How r u '+@i+'. --Needed output here is How r u 100.
104 How r u 100.
105 How r u '+@i+'. 
106 How r u 99.
107 How r u '+@i+'. 
108 How r u 98.
109 How r u '+@i+'. 
110 How r u 97.
111 How r u '+@i+'.
```

Comment: The answer is both the combination of answers so I will not mark as the answer.

Comment: Please choose Justin's answer - it gets you where you want to go; mine only explains where you're at.

Comment: As the Jonathan Leffler said. I agree with what he said

Comment: The answer to solve this is from @Justin Pihony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this in your loop:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (Data)
SELECT REPLACE(SampleData, '@i', CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(500)))
FROM Table2
```

Comment: Thanks, please do not forget to accept this as the answer then :)

Comment: Ultimately, the question asker has the right to not pick an answer.  It is irksome, but legal.  We've both done what can be done; the rest is out of our control.  Relax.  Answer a few more questions.  Many answers reaps the rewards - see Jon Skeet for an example.  Agonizing over a single answer is, sad to say, fruitless.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I totally agree, but when I see new posters (people with reputations less than 100), I at least try to point it out. I am not agonizing, moreso I am trying to educate :)...if that makes sense

Comment: Your one hint was fair.  I also pointed out correct etiquette with my standardized 'Welcome to StackOverflow' comment to the question itself. (I copy that message from my activity records, reinstating the URLs each time, which is a tad fiddly.)  Going beyond one hint is seldom beneficial and tends to make you look...over-concerned about reputation?  If you decide to do a more 'thorough' hint, delete the original one; leave just one behind.  (I'm not sure whether this conversation should be left for others to learn from, or whether it is better deleted.)

Comment: Haha, if somebody does indeed stumble upon this, I think it would be better to leave it as is. In fact, it might be something for meta? if it is not already there. I tend to forget about deleting comments, or else I would have in favor of the more descriptive one. Again, I think I may leave this up as is for future users who might stumble on it, and I do appreciate the insight

Answer (score 0):

The first INSERT places a constant string in the table:

```
insert into Table2 (SampleData) values ('How r u ''+@i+''. ')
```

There happens to be an `@` in it, and a couple of single quotes (each represented by two single quotes), but the string is just:

```
How r u '+@i'.
```

When you later do:

```
Set @TempSampleData = (select SampleData from Table2)
insert into Table1 (Data ) values (@TempSampleData)
```

This takes a direct copy of the value from Table2 and copies it into Table1.  There is no evaluation done on the string; there shouldn't be any evaluation done on the string.  I'm not even sure if there is a way to get the string evaluated - and it would probably need a lot more quotes to produce a valid value if it was possible.

The other INSERT operation is different:

```
insert into Table1 (Data) values ('How r u '+Cast(@i as varchar(500))+'.')
```

Here, the string to be inserted is evaluated as the statement is executed.  It converts the current value of the variable `i` to a string and concatenates that with two other string fragments.

Comment: you are right about the concept. but in the Last the string is hardcoded in the script that I don't want to do. The alternative method was provided by @Justin Pihony